# File Download in PrimeFaces DataTable Issue Hangs Up

Tags: primefaces, datatable, javabeans

I have files stored as blobs in a database.  I want to display them in a data table along with other information.  I am trying to download files from the data table on click of a hyperlink.  I am not able to click on the hyperlink and when the table gets loaded I am seeing download message for the entire page in my logs for my first page (I set the page size to 10) so I see 10 messages.  I am also seeing the message from JDBC 10 times giving me the different file names.

This is my xhtml:

```
            </p:column>
    <p:column sortBy="#{inv.sizeMB}" filterBy="#{inv.sizeMB}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="File Name" />
        </f:facet>
            <p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{inv.downloadFile(inv.id)}" />
            </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This is my bean code:

```
        public DefaultStreamedContent downloadFile(Integer invID)    {
    System.out.println("Downloading inv " + invID);
    DefaultStreamedContent toReturn = null;
    try {  
        toReturn = dbConnector.downloadinv(invID);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(invBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

This is my JDBC code:

```
         public DefaultStreamedContent downloadinv(Integer invID) throws SQLException   {
    DefaultStreamedContent toReturn = null;
    PreparedStatement downloadStatement = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT "
            + " FILE_NAME, FILE_DATA FROM inv.INV_META WHERE INV_ID=?");
    java.sql.Blob blob;
    downloadStatement.setInt(1, invID);
    ResultSet downloadResults = null;
    downloadResults = downloadStatement.executeQuery();

    if (downloadResults != null && downloadResults.next()) {
        blob = downloadResults.getBlob("FILE_DATA");
        int iLength = (int) (blob.length());
        if(iLength > 0) {
            String fileName = downloadResults.getString("FILE_NAME");
            String fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            System.out.println("File extension of " + fileName + ": " + fileType);

            byte barr[] = new byte[(int) blob.length()];
            barr = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(barr);

            String fileExt = "";
            if (fileType.trim().toLowerCase().contains("zip")) {
                fileExt = "application/zip";
            } else if (fileType.trim().toLowerCase().contains("doc")) {
                fileExt = "application/msword";
            } else if (fileType.trim().toLowerCase().contains("pptx")) {
                fileExt = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.inv";
            } else if (fileType.trim().toLowerCase().contains("ppt")) {
                fileExt = "application/ppt";
            } else if (fileType.trim().toLowerCase().contains("pdf")) {
                fileExt = "application/pdf";
            } else {
                fileExt = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InvJDBC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println(barr);
            toReturn = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, fileExt, fileName);
        }
    }
    downloadResults.close();
    downloadStatement.close();
    return toReturn;
}
```

I am seeing the following in my logs:

```
    Downloading inv 2468
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@1a3e5ad4
    Downloading inv 2470
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@17264b15
    Downloading inv 2471
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@1d95e165
    Downloading inv 2472
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@7d624027
    Downloading inv 2473
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@6689be00
    Downloading inv 2474
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@645bc2c4
    Downloading inv 2466
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@39300c32
    Downloading inv 2467
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@7d16339e
    Downloading inv 2475
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@43379047
    Downloading inv 2476
    File extension of inv.txt: txt
    [B@3cb0d361
```

Comment: What is the "download message for the entire page" you are seeing in your logs?

Comment: I am seeing the following in my logs:

Comment: Just a guess: try to change the `p:commandLink` by `p:commandButton`. As stated on https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2944 there are some problems mixing `p:commandLink` and `p:fileDownload`

Comment: Tried command button, did not work.  My bean has properties @SessionScoped @ManagedBean(name = "invBean", eager = true).  I am calling downloadinv method from this bean to download the file.  This bean is also used to populate the data table.  Do I need to move the download code out of the bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `p:fileDownload` is executing the method at render-time, as it evaluates the `value` attribute. If `inv` is the name of your iteration variable, you should write the component as:

```
<p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false">
      <p:fileDownload value="#{inv.file}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

And on `inv`'s class, add a `getFile` method:

```
public DefaultStreamedContent getFile() throws SQLException   {
    DefaultStreamedContent toReturn = null;
    PreparedStatement downloadStatement = dbConn.prepareStatement(
                              "SELECT FILE_NAME, FILE_DATA "+
                              "  FROM inv.INV_META "+
                              " WHERE INV_ID=?");
    java.sql.Blob blob;
    downloadStatement.setInt(1, invID);
    ResultSet downloadResults = null;
    downloadResults = downloadStatement.executeQuery();

    .....
}
```

Comment: @user7517586 glad to have helped. If this answer was right, please mark it as correct to help other people having similar issues.